# NextJS: i18n sub-path routing without locale name

Tags: routes, internationalization, next.js

According to NextJS docs

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#sub-path-routing

We can have different localized routes by adding locale name `/es/hello` `/fr/hello` ...

Is it possible to implement this without adding the locale name and having different routes? `/hola` `/salut` ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it, if this is a single case, would be to use rewrite rules. For your example you could use the following:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/hola',
            destination: '/es/greeting
        },
        {
            source: '/salut',
            destination: '/fr/greeting
        },
    ];
},
```

With this configuration you will need to have greeting.jsx in your pages folder which will handle all the languages. The locale will be accessible, as always, through the router.

Comment: `rewrites` only redirect to new page. However, it could not generate each page in the path. Try to use `exportPathMap` with SSG for better SEO.

Answer (score 1):

In `next.config.js`, add

```js
exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      'es/hello': { page: '/hello' },
      'fr/hello': { page: '/hello' },
    }
  },
```

Then it will generate multiple pages such as

```
http://example.com/es/hello
http://example.com/fr/hello
```

which has the same content as `./hello` component.

After that, you could try to use [react-intl-universal](https://fe-tool.com/react-intl-universal) with next.js. Here is an example [integrating react-intl-universal with NextJS](https://github.com/alibaba/react-intl-universal/tree/master/packages/react-intl-universal/examples/browser-example).